# Considering the consistency of an Aggregate root when referencing another Aggregate root in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, consistency, aggregateroot

In DDD an aggregate root may reference another one by direct object reference(or pointer) or by identity.

Also DDD implies that an aggregate root must ensure the invariants and the consistency of the whole aggregate boundaries, But when I was reading vaughn vernon's book he mentioned when he was talking about designing **Product** and **BackLogItem** aggregates that :

> DDD states that one aggregate may hold references to the root of other
>   aggregates.However, we must keep in mind that this doesn't place the
>   referenced aggregate inside the consistency-boundary of the one
>   referencing it.

I am new to DDD and I was thinking that the BackLogItem aggregate root by referencing the Product aggregate root, it becomes one of it's children and ensuring it's consistency is the responsibility of BackLogItem,for example we cannot plan new BackLogItem in case of the Product is suspended(I know that this example may not be a situation of scrum-based applications).

So my question is: should ensuring the consistency of Product inside BackLogItem aggregate be by Product or by BackLogItem aggregate root?

Answer (score 2):

> In DDD an aggregate root may reference another one by direct object reference(or pointer) or by identity.

Yes, that's consistent with how Eric Evans introduced the pattern in 2003.

> So my question is: should ensuring the consistency of Product inside BackLogItem aggregate be by Product or by BackLogItem aggregate root?

That question is a bit twisted up -- we don't try to enforce immediate consistency across aggregate boundaries.

In other words, if it is [expensive to the business](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/) when backlog items and products are not in agreement, then we re-design the model so that those two *entities* are part of the same aggregate.

On the other hand, if it is *not* expensive to the business; because it's not a big deal, or because it's easily fixed; then we can keep the design that puts these entities in separate aggregate, but accept that we'll be *detecting and fixing* inconsistencies, rather than preventing them.

For instance, if the UI only permits planning a new backlog item for products that are not suspended, then we only have a problem if the product is suspended between the update to the product that the UI is looking at, and the arrival of the message planning the new item.

[Udi Dahan](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/) suggested this framing: does it really matter much to the business if the message planning a new backlog item appears milliseconds before a product is suspended rather than milliseconds after?  If it really does, then every transaction that involves one should necessarily involve the other.  If it doesn't, then don't insist on forcing it.

If the domain model isn't responsible for making the decision, you want to be really careful about what consistency you impose.  See Greg Young's discussion of [warehouse systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=10m48s).  In your specific example, the decision to add an item to the backlog probably came from a *person*, rather than from the domain model itself; likewise, the decision to suspend a product also came from a person.  It will often make sense to record *both* decisions, and detect that they are in conflict, rather than trying to have the model veto a decision that has already been made.  (Note: you might still want to do this even if you decide that products and backlog items do belong in the same aggregate).

Comment: Depending on his example  because of the Product aggregate root is a child entity inside  BackLogItem, why we cannot use the Product Aggregate in ensuring some invariants inside BackLogItem such as checking it's suspended or not when planning new BackLog item (here I don't mean to ensure the same consistency boundries when do transactions on Product aggregate)